# Defining a thread id to a object and interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have threads dedicated to users on a system, and I want to be able to stop them individually, do I store the ID of the thread with the userdata at creation and then call an interrupt? or can I somehow add the thread to my user objects and just call it like `myuser.mythread.interrupt();` or is this whishing for magic?

Currently I can stop them all and restart without the thread I want. 
But that is a time consuming task and also triggers a lag where users must wait.

Update, can this be an answer?

```
if(delete==true) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == deleteId) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        delete=false;
    }
}
```

Update

I managed to find a way to use myuser.mythread.interrupt(); 
Or sort of..

I added the thread as a sub class to the user class and created a method in the user class to start and interrupt, now i can start and stop threads with

```
online.get(1).hellos();
online.get(1).hellosStop();
```

Instead of having to create a reference and keeping track of anything else than the user objects.

Update (regarding accepted answer, using the id as a reference I could do it this way)

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private boolean runThread = true;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { 
            while (runThread) {
               if(delete==true) {
                   if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == deleteId) {
                       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                       delete=false;
                   } 
                }
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            // Interrupted, no need to check flag, just exit
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just store the `Thread` reference, perhaps in a `WeakReference` so that the thread will go away if it exits on its own.

But you can also have the Thread check an AtomicBoolean (or volatile boolean) every now and then to see if it was interrupted, that way you don't need a reference to the thread.

Note though that stopping threads in Java is not possible without cooperation from the thread you want to stop.  It doesn't matter if you use `interrupt` or a boolean that it checks, in both cases it is up to the thread to check these flags (`interrupt` just sets a flag) and then perform some action like exiting.

**Update**
A sample interruptable thread class:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean stopFlag;

    public MyRunnable(AtomicBoolean stopFlag) {
        this.stopFlag = stopFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { // Try/Catch only needed if you use locks/sleep etc.
            while (!stopFlag.get()) {
                // Do some work, but remember to check flag often!
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {  
            // Interrupted, no need to check flag, just exit
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I too would have a `while(!Thread.interupted() && isActive)` (where isActive is an `AtomicBoolean` that can be switched from outside) containing the main loop of the thread. But maybe OP cannot change the content of their threads' Runnable.

Comment: Ok. currently i have a boolean var that I set to true or false to destroy the threads or cause a interrupt catch and in that catch i run interrupt again. which has worked, but it controls all threads. Is there a way to "programmaticly" add a variable indicator to control thread? like `boolean run_+thread1 = true;`? so have the thread running `while(run_+getPassedData){`

Comment: Just add a field to your thread.  When creating threads, make sure its constructor accepts an AtomicBoolean in its constructor.  This boolean can then be modified to signal the thread to stop.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get it working, gives me error saying that boolean is required, where do i put/check the isOff?

`class sts implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean isOff;

    public sts(AtomicBoolean turnOff) {
        this.isOff = turnOff;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (isOff) {`

Comment: Also, I would need a reference either way? cause i need to change the var inside the thread i want, now isOff is the same in all threads and every thread will stop when I change isOff?

Comment: I just read up on atomicboolean, and understand there is a bit more work to it than what i posted. but I stumbled upon this, and this is sort of what I'm looking for I think. Is this an ok way to destroy/stop the thread?

`Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

for(Thread thread : setOfThread){
    if(thread.getId()==MyStoredReference){
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}`

Comment: Ok, thank you! But have to give the  atomicBoolean some kind of identification. So got to have my automaticly added variables to be able to change the atomic boolean of each thread. now it is the same as having boolean stopFlag = true, or boolearn stopFlag = false;

Comment: I mean if I have 40 sts threads running at the same time, and call a change to stopFlag without any id then all threads will stop.

Comment: Take a look at my updated question, I have added what I think can be the solution, what do you think?

Comment: You really should post more code so we can help better, because you are still thinking of terms of what you have now instead of understanding what was suggested.

Comment: the only difference in code was the atomicboolean and there was no way to identify the atomicboolean I have to change to stop a individual thread so that it stops/interrupts.

Comment: I had the same code you posted except i have a regular boolean in while which I can toggle true/false from outside the thread. problem is, it's toggeling all the threads. Same as your AtomicBoolean will as it is never unique. My edited post/question code snippet goes inside the while(everRunningToIInterrupt){* block here* } and will work right? but is it a safe way?

Comment: Or,if your way is better to use, how to initiate a unique atomicboolean for each thread? only way to start them is with AtomicBoolean aBool = new AtomicBoolean(true); right? do I store each of the aBool's in a map or something to identify it later or what?

Comment: It depends on how you create all those threads, you never posted that code.  There's so many ways to do this that I can only guess, it could even be that you should be using one of the frameworks in Java that help with thread management, like ExecutorService or CompletableFuture's.

Comment: @john16384 I understand. I was creating them "normally", when the program action is fired  `Thread recs = new Thread(new sts(extrasStore)); ` is called and thread created

But changed a lot to be able to call `objectClass.objectIdToChange.stopThread();`  now i add items to objectClass and start thread in that object just after creation. and the thread is in the objectClass not in the main thread

Comment: I'm going to accept this as an answer anyway, though it did not give the solution I am using (myobject.objectid.stopThread();), you mentioned that I could store the id, which I then could use in the if(delete) example i gave. so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to save the `Thread` reference and make it available to the code that needs to interrupt it.

It is technically possible (for a non-sandboxed application) to traverse the tree of all of the JVM's existing threads testing each one.  However, that is expensive and doesn't scale.  And if you can store or pass the id of a thread, then you should be able to store or pass the `Thread` reference instead.

It is also technically possible to create your own `WeakHashMap<Long, Thread>` and use that to map thread ids to threads.  But the same argument applies ....

You ask if this is a solution:

```
if (delete) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().getId() == deleteId) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        delete = false;
    }
}
```

No it isn't.  Or more precisely, it will only "work" in the case where the thread is interrupting itself.  In other cases, the target thread won't be interrupted.

---

Depending on your use-case, another way to do this could be to use an `ExecutionService` rather than bare threads.  The `submit` methods return a `Future` object that represents the submitted task.  The object has a `cancel(...)` method that can be used to cancel the task, either before it runs, or by interrupting the running thread.

Comment: Ok i think i understand. But that "if(delete)" is in the current thread, so it is not searching and when the global delete is true, whatever thread which has the same id as the global var deleteId will be deleted?

And I found a way to have the thread in the user class to i can now just identify the user class by user.get(id).callStop();

Comment: Hmm, I will look into ExecutionService to see what it is. I'm doing alot of data transfer and I read that runnable threads are the best alternative for continuous tasks